# python aio libray logs and async method logs not showing in function application insights

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, python-asyncio

I am using python aio management client library to create azure resources , for example `azure.mgmt.eventhub.aio.EventHubManagementClient`

**Observation** :

- While counterpart azure sync libraries(for example `azure.mgmt.eventhub.EventHubManagementClient` ) print http logs when management service API is called, but async libraries doesn't print similar logs
- Also when I use async method and use python logger in async methods , Even those logs doesn't print .

**Sample Code**

```
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    async def _create_or_update_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule(self, authorization_rule_name,
                                                                  rights: AccessRights):
    await self._event_management_client.namespaces.create_or_update_authorization_rule(
        resource_group_name=EnvironmentVariables.RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        namespace_name=self._env_var_obj.event_hub_name_space_name,
        authorization_rule_name=authorization_rule_name,
        parameters={
            "rights": [rights]
        }
    )

    logger.info('Provisioned EH-Namespace Rule:' + authorization_rule_name)
```

Here both `create_or_update_authorization_rule()` and my own log doesn't show in Azure function insights.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved when I defined the the azure function main function itself as async function, Azure python workers handle manages the event loop and calls this main method asynchronously

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
```

With this all aio client logs and my own logs are getting logged in app insights .

**Note** :
Earlier I was defining above method as non-async , then used to call async mehtod from main() by explicitly creating event loop and using `asgiref.async_to_sync` library